# How to stylize a text background accurately with CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying make a transparent text background and the background should fill as far as any character goes.

If I use `display:inline-block` both line gets the same background width so filling text background effect is missing and that's not what I am trying to achieve.

getting on top one another can be fixed by increasing line height, or setting the line height `normal` but that makes huge gap between lines. Well I would like to have both line very close. which in this case is 55px line height with font-size of 47px.

Markup here:

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 30px;
}
.test {
  width: 450px;
}
.main h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 47px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.main h2 span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="test">
    <h2><span>A title about your dream kitchen</span></h2>
    <a href="">Read MOre</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Check in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srmahmud2/ze4kpmuy/

not sure can I make you understand or not. here a screenshot for quick look
http://postimg.org/image/efnmpoiy1/

Comment: So you want each line to have the background go to the edge, but have them be close to each other without overlap?

Comment: I changed your `line-height:` to `52px` instead of `55px` and it closed the gap. Not sure if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using drop shadows, courtesy of [this blog](http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/). Here is the style for the `.main h2 span`:

```
.main h2 span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
             -10px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slushy/mu8rwcjp/